# Getting error while displaying any component from Antd after upgrading Antd v3 to v4

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am getting an error to get Antd components rendered after upgrading from v3 to v4.`Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.` Provided link shows that the error is regarding calling hooks. However, I am not using hooks in the code yet. I have upgraded react and react-dom to v16.13.1